# Filtering a set of data

Tags: excel, filtering, excel-2010, worksheet-function

So I have a document that I work with, in which I input daily data. This data is recorded for the entire year in one spreadsheet. This data is also used to calculate monthly values for graphs and such. In order to make the input of this data simpler and less repetitive, I wanted to link the monthly spreadsheet to the yearly one, so that one only needs to fill out the yearly compilation of data.

Is there any way to write a formula that goes through the data in the yearly spreadsheet and only pulls out the data for a certain month? If so, what is the best function to use?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two columns, one has the date the other an amount as below:

[image]

Using SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, criteria_range2, criteria2) will allow you to sum all amounts in the sum range ($B$2:$B$10) for any dates that fall in between two dates you specify in E1 and E2.

The formula would be: =SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,">="&E1,A2:A10,"<="&E2)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `=Vlookup()`  if you are just pulling data from the yearly into the monthly.  If you are trying to calculate daily data into monthly data you could us the `countif()` or `sumif()` functions depending on what you want to accomplish.  So if you are trying to add up all of the daily data to get the monthly amount you would do something like:
 `=sumif(range,critera,[sumrange])`  range would be the celss that that months are in criteria would be the month and sumrange would be the values of the months.